# Assigning new classes to bootstrap elements at screen resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-resolution

Im trying to change a [FONT-AWESOME](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) glyphicon class from fa-3x size to fa-2x size when the window reaches 991px or smaller. It also needs to change when the window loads at 991px or smaller... here's two options I tried:

### JAVASCRIPT METHOD 1:

```
/*CHANGE CLASS OF #glyph2 AT 991 OR LESS VW DURING DOCUMENT READY*/
    if( $(window).innerWidth() <= 991)
      {document.getElementById('#glyph2').className = "fa fa-caret-right fa-2x";} 
    else if( $(window).innerWidth() > 991)
      {document.getElementById('#glyph2').className = "fa fa-caret-right fa-3x";} 

/*CHANGE CLASS OF #glyph2 AT 991 OR LESS VW DURING RESIZE*/
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if( $(window).innerWidth() <= 991)    
      {document.getElementById('#glyph2').className = "fa fa-caret-right fa-2x";} 
    else if( $(window).innerWidth() > 991)  
      {document.getElementById('#glyph2').className = "fa fa-caret-right fa-3x";};
});
```

AND

### JAVASCRIPT METHOD 2:

```
(function($) {
var $window = $(window),
    $glyph2 = $('#glyph2');

function resize() {
    if ($window.width() <= 991) {
        return $glyph2.addClass('fa fa-caret-right fa-2x');
    }
    $glyph2.addClass('fa fa-caret-right fa-3x');
}

$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Neither of these two options works.. Any ideas or fixes would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EASIER CSS AND MEDIA QUERIES METHOD:

Probably the best and easiest method - using only Media Queries and CSS:

HTML CODE:

```
<button id="btn6" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><p id="btn6Text">READ MORE ABOUT US<i id="glyph2" class="fa fa-caret-right fa-3x"></i></p></button>
```

CSS CODE:

```
/* When SCREEN VW <= 991px ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 991px) {

/* Styles */
#glyph2 {
    font-size: 2em !important;
}

}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/MaartenPAC/8pm2ycvg/)

Answer (score 0):

(Found a fix! Instead of changing the class, I simply rewrite the html code each time the window ends up smaller than 991px:

### Using Javascript method1:

HTML CODE:

```
<button id="btn6" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><p id="btn6Text">READ MORE ABOUT US<i id="glyph2" class="fa fa-caret-right fa-3x"></i></p></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
/*CHANGE CLASS OF #glyph2 AT 991 OR LESS VW DURING DOCUMENT READY*/
if( $(window).innerWidth() <= 991)
  {document.getElementById("btn6Text").innerHTML = "READ MORE ABOUT US<i id='glyph2' class='fa fa-caret-right fa-2x'></i>";}
else if( $(window).innerWidth() > 991)
  {document.getElementById("btn6Text").innerHTML = "READ MORE ABOUT US<i id='glyph2' class='fa fa-caret-right fa-3x'></i>";}

/*CHANGE CLASS OF #glyph2 AT 991 OR LESS VW DURING RESIZE*/
$(window).resize(function () {
if( $(window).innerWidth() <= 991)    
  {document.getElementById("btn6Text").innerHTML = "READ MORE ABOUT US<i id='glyph2' class='fa fa-caret-right fa-2x'></i>";} 
else if( $(window).innerWidth() > 991)  
  {document.getElementById("btn6Text").innerHTML = "READ MORE ABOUT US<i id='glyph2' class='fa fa-caret-right fa-3x'></i>";};
});
```

So each time the window ends up less than 991px, I rewrite these code:

```
<button id="btn6" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><p id="btn6Text">READ MORE ABOUT US<i id="glyph2" class="fa fa-caret-right fa-3x"></i></p></button>
```

To this:

```
<button id="btn6" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><p id="btn6Text">READ MORE ABOUT US<i id="glyph2" class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x"></i></p></button>
```

Difference: fa-3x changes to code with fa-2x

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a CSS only and Font-Awesome/Bootstrap styled solution,
here's what you can do:

Create some new CSS Classes to represent the lg, 2x, 3x, 4x and 5x. One for each bootstrap screen size that you want (`sm`, `md` and `lg`, for instance). Then use `@media` on them.

You will end up with something like this:

```
/* sm */
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .fa-3x-sm {
        font-size: 3em !important;
    }
    .fa-2x-sm {
        font-size: 2em !important;
    }
    .fa-lg-sm {
        font-size: 1.33333333em !important;
        line-height: 0.75em !important;
        vertical-align: -15% !important;
    }
}
/* md */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .fa-3x-md {
        font-size: 3em !important;
    }
    .fa-2x-md {
        font-size: 2em !important;
    }
    .fa-lg-md {
        font-size: 1.33333333em !important;
        line-height: 0.75em !important;
        vertical-align: -15% !important;
    }
}
/* lg */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .fa-3x-lg {
        font-size: 3em !important;
    }
    .fa-2x-lg {
        font-size: 2em !important;
    }
    .fa-lg-lg {
        font-size: 1.33333333em !important;
        line-height: 0.75em !important;
        vertical-align: -15% !important;
    }
}
```

I'm using only the `fa-lg`, `fa-2x` and `fa-3x` to keep it short.
With that, you could use a `fa-3x-lg` to get a 3x sized icon on lg resolution and a regular sized icon on smaller screens.

Or, you could combine some of them just like you would on bootstrap solutions, just like using a `fa-2x-sm fa-3x-md`would give you 3x sized icons on `md` screen size and up, 2x sized icon on `sm` screen size and a regular sized icon on even smaller screens.

It's just like using some of bootstrap's convention on the FontAwesome sizing classes.

Hope it helps.